# Getting error Mysql. PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I created a profile.php page but after I log in into my user profile, I want to display the users info. I get the following error.

> Error MessageFatal error: Call to a member function Fetch() on a non-object in /home/a6150953/public_html/profile.php on line 16` anyone could help me with a solution please.

profile.php

```
  <?php
    session_start();
    //session_destroy();

    include_once('php/classes/class.user.php');

    $user1 = new User($con);

    if(isset($_POST['logout'])) {
            session_destroy();
            header('Location: index.php');
    }

    include_once('php/common/head.php');

    $all    =   $con->Fetch("select * from users");

?>
    <div class="wrapper">
    <h1>
    <?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['uid'])){
        echo "Profile Page for  ". $all[0]['fullname'] ." ";
    }else{
        echo "Welcome", "<br/><a href='index.php'>Login</a>";
    }
    ?>
    </h1>
    <pre>
    <div id="profile">
    <?php
    if(isset($_GET['uid']) || isset($_SESSION['uid'])) {

        if($_GET['uid'] == $_SESSION['uid']) {

            echo " " . $all[0]['fullname'] . "  ";

            echo "<form action='' method='post'>
                <input type='hidden' name='logout' value='true' />
                <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Logout'>
            </form>";

        }else if($user1->check_user($uid)){

            echo '<p>'.$all[0]['fullname'].'</p>';
            echo '<p>'.$all[0]['uemail'].'</p>';

        }else if(!$user1->check_user($uid)){
            echo "Invalid User";
        }

    }else{
        echo "Incorrect";
    }
    ?>
    </pre>
    </div>
    </div>
    <?php include_once('php/common/foot.php'); ?>
```

DB_CONFIG.php

```
<?php
    class   DBEngine
        {
            public  $con;
            public  $errors;
            public  function __construct("LOGIN CREDENTIALS CANT SHOW")
                {
                    try {
                            $this->con  =   new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db",$user,$pass, array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING));
                        }
                    catch (Exception $e) {
                          $this->errors['connect']['message']    =   $e->getMessage();
                          $this->errors['connect']['error_code'] =   $e->getCode();
                        }
                }

                public  function Fetch($_sql)
                {
                    $query  =   $this->con->prepare($_sql);
                    $query->execute();
                    $this->errors['fetch'][]    =   $query->errorInfo();

                    if($query->rowCount() > 0) {
                            while($rows = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                                    $array[]    =   $rows;
                                }
                        }

                    return (isset($array) && $array !== 0 && !empty($array))? $array: 0;
                }

            // Simple write to db method
            public  function Write($_sql)
                {
                    $query  =   $this->con->prepare($_sql);
                    $query->execute();
                    $this->errors['insert'][]   =   $query->errorInfo();
                }
        }

// To use/initialize
$con = new DBEngine(); ?>
```

CLASS.USER.PHP

```
    <?php
class User
    {
        public  $db;
        public  $error;

        public function __construct($con){
                $this->db = $con;
        }

        /*** for login process ***/
        public function check_login($username='', $password=''){
                // Validate that your email is a real one
                if(filter_var($username,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) !== false) {
                        $password   =   md5($password);
                        $sql        =   "SELECT uid from users WHERE (uemail='$username' or uname='$username') and upass = '$password'";
                        $result     =   $this->db->Fetch($sql);

                            if ($result !== 0) {
                                    // this login var will use for the session thing
                                    $_SESSION['emailusername']  =   $result[0]['uemail'];
                                    $_SESSION['uid']            =   $result[0]['uid'];
                                    $_SESSION['user']           =   $this->get_fullname($result[0]['uid'],0);
                                    $_SESSION['login']          =   true;
                                }
                            else
                                $this->error['account'] = 'Invalid Username/Password';
                    }
                else
                    $this->error['email'] = 'Invalid Email Address';

                return  (!isset($_SESSION['emailusername']))? false:true;
            }

        /*** for showing the username or fullname ***/
        public function get_fullname($uid, $write = 1){

                // --> You can prepare, bind, and execute your values here replacing what you have now....<--
                $sql                =   "SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid = $uid";
                $user_data          =   $this->db->Fetch($sql);

                if($user_data !== 0) {
                        $user['fullname']   =   $user_data['fullname'];
                        $user['uemail']     =   $user_data['uemail'];
                        $user['uid']        =   $user_data['uid'];

                        // This gives the option of returning an array (setting session array) or echoing
                        if($write == 1)
                            echo implode("<br />",$user);
                        else
                            return $user;
                    }
            }

        public function check_user($uid)
            {
                $sql        =   "SELECT * from users WHERE uid='$uid'";
                $result     =   $this->db->Fetch($sql);
                $count_row  =   ($result !== 0)? count($result): 0;

                return ($count_row == 1);
            }

        /*** starting the session ***/
        public function get_session()
            {
                return $_SESSION['login'];
            }

        public function user_logout()
            {
                $_SESSION['login'] = FALSE;
                session_destroy();
            }
    }
?>
```

UPDATE :

STILL GETTING AN ERROR ::::: `Call to undefined method USER::FETCH() in line 16`

Comment: I hope that's not your live login credentials to MySQL

Comment: Sidenote: Whoever told you that MD5 is safe to use, isn't your friend.

Comment: its just for testing @Fred-ii-, I know its not safe.

Comment: Why you vote me down for people?????????? isnt this enough explanatory about my problem. God Damn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the DBEngine Class page and use `$con` still.

```
include_once('php/classes/DB_CONFIG.php');
```

You are only including the `User` class page, so should be:

```
// DB Class
include_once('php/classes/DB_CONFIG.php');
// User class
include_once('php/classes/class.user.php');
// $con is your DB class, and `Fetch` is in that class
$all    =   $con->Fetch("select * from users");
```

Comment: Call to undefined method USER::FETCH() in line 16 error :(

Comment: See my revision. You are not including the DB page to get your `Fetch()` from.

Comment: when i navigate to a user other than the one logged in i get the following error: `Call to a member function check_user() on a non-object in /home/a6150953/public_html/profile.php on line 45`

Comment: Is that this line `}else if(!$user1->check_user($uid)){`?

Comment: thats correct, i changed the $user1 = $all and no matter which user gets logged in it still displays the 1st users details from DB

Comment: Oh, don't do that. You are getting the things mixed up. The `$user1` is your `User` class and the `$con` is your DB query/connection class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63878/discussion-between-rasclatt-and-love-php).

Answer (score 1):

Change this to:

```
$all    =   $con->Fetch("select * from users");
            //here con is construct parameter not an object
```

to this:

```
$all    =   $user1->Fetch("select * from users");
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to include your database class:

Add this to the top of your script:

```
include_once('path/to/DB_CONFIG.php');
```

Answer (score 1):

$all = $user1->Fetch("select * from users");